# Inheritance for durandal (HotTowel) viewmodels?

Tags: durandal, hottowel

Simple question, pretty sure it's a complicated answer :)

Is it possible to implement some form of inheritance for viewmodels in Durandal?

So if you have a viewmodel something like this:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'services/datacontext', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'services/logger'],
    function (app, datacontext, router, logger) {
        var someVariable = ko.observable();
        var isSaving = ko.observable(false);

        var vm = {
            activate: activate,
            someVariable : someVariable,
            refresh: refresh,
            cancel: function () { router.navigateBack(); },
            hasChanges: ko.computed(function () { return datacontext.hasChanges(); }),
            canSave: ko.computed(function () { return datacontext.hasChanges() && !isSaving(); }),
            goBack: function () { router.navigateBack(); },
            save: function() {
                isSaving(true);
                return datacontext.saveChanges().fin(function () { isSaving(false); })
            },
            canDeactivate: function() {
                if (datacontext.hasChanges()) {
                    var msg = 'Do you want to leave and cancel?';
                    return app.showMessage(msg, 'Navigate Away', ['Yes', 'No'])
                        .then(function(selectedOption) {
                            if (selectedOption === 'Yes') {
                                datacontext.cancelChanges();
                            }
                            return selectedOption;
                        });
                }
                return true;
            }
        };

        return vm;

        //#region Internal Methods
        function activate(routeData) {
            logger.log('View Activated for id {' + routeData.id + '}, null, 'View', true);
            });
        }
        //#endregion

        function refresh(id) {
            return datacontext.getById(client, id);
        }
    });
```

Is it possible to make that into some kind of base type and inherit further viewmodels from it, being able to extend the requires list and so on?

There is another question on this, but the viewmodels don't appear to be quite the same as the one's that I build for durandal/HotTowel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just based off what your saying I came up with this. Let me know if this works for you and if it doesn't then let me know what I did wrong.

Thanks.

## viewmodelBase

```
define(['durandal/app', 'services/datacontext', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'services/logger'],
    function (app, datacontext, router, logger) {
        var vm = function () {
            var self = this;
            this.someVariable = ko.observable();
            this.isSaving = ko.observable(false);
            this.hasChanges = ko.computed(function () { return datacontext.hasChanges(); });
            this.canSave = ko.computed(function () { return datacontext.hasChanges() && !self.isSaving(); });
        };

        vm.prototype = {
            activate: function (routeData) {
                logger.log('View Activated for id {' + this.routeData.id + '}', null, 'View', true);
            },
            refresh: function (id) {
                return datacontext.getById(client, id);
            },
            cancel: function () {
                router.navigateBack();
            },
            goBack: function () { router.navigateBack(); },
            save: function() {
                var self = this;
                this.isSaving(true);
                return datacontext.saveChanges().fin(function () { self.isSaving(false); })
            },
            canDeactivate: function() {
                if (datacontext.hasChanges()) {
                    var msg = 'Do you want to leave and cancel?';
                    return app.showMessage(msg, 'Navigate Away', ['Yes', 'No'])
                        .then(function(selectedOption) {
                            if (selectedOption === 'Yes') {
                                datacontext.cancelChanges();
                            }
                            return selectedOption;
                        });
                }
                return true;
            }
        };

        return vm;
    });
```

## parent viewmodel

```
define([viewmodelBase], function (vmbase) {
    var vm1 = new vmbase();
    vm1.newProperty = "blah";
    var vm2 = new vmbase();
});
```

Comment: Hi Evan.  Apologies I've not gotten back to this for so long.  Question; on your approach, can you extend the injected services?  So in your base you have app, datacontext, etc. and in the child [viewModelBase].  Can you simply extend that with ([viewModelBase], 'services/service1', 'services/service2', function (vmbase, service1, serivce2) ?

Comment: With javascript there are all types of patterns around how to do inheritance.  They all have their benifits and some are more complicated than others.  I would just google javascript prototype inheritance and find a solution that fits your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this can be accomplished with jQuery's extend method. This just occurred to me, so there may be something that I'm missing, but a basic example would be something along the lines of:

**basevm.js**

```
... your mentioned viewmodel
```

**inheritingvm.js**

```
define(['basevm'], function (basevm) {
   var someNewObservable = ko.observable();

   var vm = $.extend({
        someNewObservable : someNewObservable
   }, basevm);

   return vm;
});
```

Please let me know if this works. I just coded from the top of my head and it hasn't been tested.

Comment: Hi, sorry I've taken so long to come back to this.  This does appear to work awesomely, but doesn't this mean that essentially every viewmodel using this technique will share the one basevm?  My understanding of durandal is that a model injected like this will have a singleton lifetime?  I may be way off though.  Thanks!

Comment: As far as I'm aware this will have a singleton lifetime, yes.

Comment: This is by far the easiest approach.  Depending on what you do with your base viewmodel, the singleton lifetime can be acceptable.  In my case, I'm using it mostly for common code, rather than common properties that might get confused with a singleton lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a post on my blog that addresses this issue. In short, I use prototypical inheritance for all of my modal dialog views in one of my projects. Here's the [link](http://codeattic.blogspot.com/2013/08/javascript-inheritance.html) to the post I wrote (feel free to skip to the code part) and a jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/EthtE/) that demonstrates it.

Simplified example that can work in Durandal (NOTE: each view-model returns its constructor function, not an object):

**viewmodels/modal.js**

```
define(['durandal/system'], 
function(system) { 
  var modal = function () {
    this.name = 'Modal';
  }

  modal.prototype = {
    activate: function() {
        system.log(this.name + ' activating');
    },
    attached: function(view) {
        system.log(this.name + ' attached');
    },
    deactivate: function() {
        system.log(this.name + ' deactivating');
    },
    detached: function(view, parent) {
        system.log(this.name + ' detached');
    }
  };

  return modal;
});
```

**viewmodels/child.js**

```
define(['durandal/system', 'viewmodels/modal'],
function(system, Modal) {
  var child = function() {
    this.name = 'Child Modal';
  }

  // inherits from Modal
  child.prototype = new Modal();
  child.prototype.constructor = child;
  child.prototype._super = Modal.prototype;

  // overrides Modal's activate() method
  child.prototype.activate = function() {
    this._super.activate.call(this);  // we can still call it from the _super property
    system.log(this.name + ' activating [overridden version]');
  };

  return child;
});
```

I prefer this implementation because it supports code reuse, conforms to OOP principles as best as javascript allows, and it gives me the ability to call the base class' methods via the _super property when I need to. You can easily convert this as needed.